# Mongodb cannot be accessed from Developer Machine

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

So, This could be a beaten to dead question, but i am posting it here because i dont have and answer and would need your help on this. 
I have my Dev application Mongo DB in a server.  I can remotely login to the server. If i install Robomongo in the dev server, i am able to access the db.

But i am trying to access the db from my laptop. On googling, i found that this is all done by using bind ip. The question i have is , what ip do i place in here ?

I have a IP4 address for my dev db sever, Public ip for my dev DB server (that can be found when i do whatsmyip.com)

i have a ip4 address for my laptop and similar public ip.

I tried all 4. but still i am not able to establish a connection.

Anyhelp on what i am missing would be helpful.

I dont have any security for my user. 
I am using Windows 2008 R2.
my config file:

```
net:
  bindIp: [127.0.0.1,xxx.xx.xx.xx]
  port: 27017
storage:
  dbPath: C:\MongoDb\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: C:\MongoDb\logs\mongo.log
  quiet: true
  logAppend: true
```

Comment: from own server where is installed mongo, accessing db works. It's when you try to remote access mongo that fails ?

Comment: @jeorfevre yes. that is correct. I just tried pinging the server. i get request timed out. But i am able to login to the remote server

Answer (score 0):

1. check firewall rules `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all`
2. check if there is port forwardnig in place (i was strugling as I had port forwarded from 8080 to 8081 and forgot about that)
3. remove `bindIp` from config - so mongo will bind all interfaces and run `netstat -a -n` and see if someone listening on 27017

> ```
> netstat -a -n
> Active Connections
>   Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
>   TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
> ....
>   TCP    0.0.0.0:34800          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your points. Please find my answers below : 1)  - checked - nothing out of ordinary. 2) - nope. nothing 3) tried this  - only my localhost (127.0.0.1) is listening.  Tried removing bindip . No effect

Comment: @Karty do you have ipv4 enabled? - this looks a bit odd

Comment: @Karty - disable firewall for a minute and try - that will be a good indicator

Comment: Disable in my laptop or server?

Comment: @Karty server side